# Opacity issue in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am trying to create opacity background color for IE in css

The css filter will change the elements to have opacity of 80 and I only want background-color to be transparent.

```
.element{

//for Chrome and FF
'background-color': rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)

//for IE..but it will make entire element having 80 opacity instead of the background-color only....   
filter:alpha(opacity=80)


}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: please specify the IE version.

Comment: your non-IE css is broken as well -- `background-color` shouldn't have quotes around it.

Comment: I need all IE version and I copy codes from JQeury.

Comment: All IE versions, eh? IE6? IE5? IE4?? And what about IE10? The IE versions you choose to support will make a very big difference to the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using an IE script called [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

This is a script that implements some of the CSS3 properties into older versions of IE, including backgrounds with alpha channel colours. This means you can write (almost) standard CSS code for IE just like all the other browsers.

With the PIE.htc file in your site, your CSS code would look like this:

```
.element{
    //for Chrome and FF
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    //for IE...
    -pie-background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

See the [CSS3Pie documentation](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background) for more info.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the gradient filter, which accepts AARRGGBB formatted colors:

```
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#80112244,endColorstr=#80112244)";
      filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#80112244,endColorstr=#80112244);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the first two digit of formatted color doesn't seem to very effective on changing opacity of the color

#90000000 is not much different than #50000000..Am I doing something wrong? +1 though

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. Try "giving layout" to the filtered element by adding `zoom: 1` to the css. Or use CSS3Pie whenever possible, it's a great solution for a lot of other problems too :)